# I want to use a class dynamically. Which is better than the following methods

Tags: php, arrays, class, dynamic

```
class foo {
    function bar($arg, $arg2) {
        echo __METHOD__, " got $arg and $arg2\n";
    }
}
```

I want to use a class dynamically. Which is better than the following methods.

Example 1:

```
$a = [ new foo, 'bar' ];
$a(...["one", "two"]);
```

Result:

foo::bar got one and two

Example 2:

```
call_user_func_array([ new foo, 'bar' ], ["one", "two"]);
```

Result:

foo::bar got one and two

Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is your **criteria of better**. I guess in most scenarios the speed difference will be insignificant. I am not a great believer in benchmarks, but here are [some benchmarks](https://github.com/fab2s/call_user_func) you can look at.

So taken that we can neglect the speed difference, we can look at coding style. **It is the matter of personal preference, but here is how I would do.** As you use [splat operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)(*>=PHP5.6*) you can call [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) directly on object, without creation of [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

```
(new foo)->{'bar'}(...["one", "two"]);
```

So consider you have a more complex class:

```
class Foo {
    public function bar($arg, $arg2)
    {
        echo __METHOD__, " got $arg and $arg2\n";
    }

    public function baz($arg)
    {
        echo __METHOD__, " got $arg\n";
    }

    public function quux()
    {
        echo __METHOD__;
    }
}
```

And have a list of methods to call:

```
$methods = [
    'bar' => ['one', 'two'],
    'baz' => ['one'],
    'quux' => []
];
```

Then the calling code will look something like the following:

```
$object = new Foo;

foreach ($methods as $method => $args) {
    $object->$method(...$args);
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/744b6a3fabed423ce3b6b86896f62c60dc55590c).

As you can see it looks more natural than using [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) or [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that.

Comment: @Scaffold, what is your question then?

Comment: What I am surprised is how a class and method in a sequence works without the need for another function. My English is not good, I can tell you.

Comment: @Scaffold, well this is a valid form of [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php): _"A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1. Accessing protected and private methods from within a class is allowed."_. That is why you can use such array as a function.